# NAT <-> NAT соединение без 3d party

Tags: сеть, lan, nat, p2p

Как подключиться p2p к компу из другой сети за prcNAT без 3 сервера, зная WAN адрес своей сети (которая тоже за prcNAT), WAN адрес другой сети и локальные адреса компов в этих сетях?

Comment: это невозможно................

Comment: а что такое prcNAT ?

Comment: @KoVadim port restricted cone NAT

Comment: Локальные адреса внутри периметра NAT вам никак не помогут. Необходимо, чтобы целевой порт целевого внутреннего сервера был forwarded на один из портов гейтвея целевой сети. Кроме того, коль скоро у вас prcNAT, нужно, чтобы внутренний сервер инциировал соединение.

Answer (score 0):

Конический нат работает только уже на установленных соединениях. Для работы без третьей стороны понадобится проброс порта на конце сервера. Можно попробовать UPnP - если роутер поддерживает - он создаст проброс порта по запросу приложения.

Но Вы также можете использовать публичные сервера STUN, SIP, Jabber, DHT не развертывая своей инфраструктуры.

Пример проброса UDP транспорта через STUN без своего сервера https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1118749/16574