# Существует ли аналог sockets, позволяющий работать с внешними адресами?

Tags: python-3.x, сеть

Я пишу p2p чат на питоне, и передо мной встала проблема подключения и запуска сервера на внешних адресах клиентов. Насколько я понимаю - стандартный модуль sockets не представляет возможностей по работе с внешними адресами. Существует ли библиотека, позволяющая работать с сокетами в глобальной сети? 
И если нет - то есть ли какие-то аналоги Hamachi, которые могли бы позволить общаться с компьютером из другой сети?

Comment: Stun и нужен сигнальный сервер

Comment: Можно как сигнальный использовать жаббер сторонний или хттп страничку

Comment: @eri а для чего нужен этот сервер?

Comment: Рассказать о внешнем адресе собеседника

Comment: Я гдето скидывал пример п2п чата

Comment: @eri Stun показал NAT type: Restric NAT. значит ли это, что я смогу только принимать соединения по порту, но не хостить их?

Comment: Ну смотри, запускаешь стун, от него получаешь ип и порт с внешки. Поднимаешь удп сокет, и делаешь сенд_ту внешний собеседника

Comment: С компа буду - напишу

Comment: что-то не нахожу свой ответ) поновой написать быстрее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения внешнего адреса и заодно открытия порта понадобится stun клиент. Его не сложно написать самому, или поставьте готовый

```
pip3 install pystun3
```

p2p чатик на двоих на голых сокетах получается такой:

```
import stun
import socket
import threading

source_ip = "0.0.0.0"
source_port = 8547

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((source_ip, source_port))
# nat_type, nat = stun.get_nat_type(sock, source_ip, source_port)

nat_type, nat = stun.get_nat_type(sock,
    source_ip, source_port,
    stun_host='stun.l.google.com', stun_port=19302 )

external_ip = nat['ExternalIP']
external_port = nat['ExternalPort']

print("Мой адрес: %s:%s" % (external_ip,external_port))

def read_chat(sock):
    while True:
       data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
       print('\r', addr,"<", data.decode())

reader = threading.Thread(target=read_chat,args=(sock,))
reader.start()

remote_ip, remote_port = input(
    "Введите `адрес:порт` другого компьютера >"
    ).split(':')
remote_port = int(remote_port)
remote = remote_ip, remote_port

while True:
    line = input(">")
    if line == '/exit':
        break
    sock.sendto(line.encode(), remote)
```

Адреса тут вводятся вручную, чтоб был как хаманчи - нужно завести сервер где клиенты будут публиковать свои адреса для установки соединения p2p.

Comment: ваш пример у меня не работает. после запуска скрипта - ничего не выводится на экран, будто уходит в вечную загрузку

Comment: pystun удали, поставь pystun3.

до какой строчки дошел?

Comment: у меня изначально стоял pystun3. скрипт не крашится и не выводит ошибку со строчкой. просто в терминале появляется пустая строка и ничего не происходит

Comment: операционка кстати какая?

Comment: Минт 19.3 кажется

Comment: код в файл сохранил?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107608/discussion-between-eri-and-gargoyle).

Comment: после CTRL+C жалуется на 11 строку -  nat_type, nat = stun.get_nat_type(sock, source_ip, source_port)