# Мессенджер на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat

Появилась мысль создать простой чат\мессенджер на Python(+- 100 участников), в следствии чего возник вопрос. Мне придется искать сервер и платить за него, или можно это сделать как-то без него? А если можно без него, то как это реализовать?

Попытки найти ответ на мой вопрос в интернете были, но либо я не понял, либо ответа на него не было. Если вы имеете представление как это сделать, прошу помочь, хотя бы книгой, роликом или статьей где будет про это говориться.

(я не в коем случае не прошу готовое решение, я просто решил спросить у людей, которые понимают в программировании лучше меня)

Comment: Всё зависит от ваших целей, технически вам никто не мешает запустить свой мессенджер хоть на обычном телефоне, лишь бы ваши 100 участников могли подключиться к этому телефону

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Я пару раз выкладывал концепт p2p месенжера на стековерфлоу.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118460/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-sockets-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/1118749#1118749) работать можно без сервера вообще, но нужен ещё один месенжер чтоб обменяться контактами для соединения.

Реализуется это через udp и stun. stun пробивает udp порт во внешнюю сеть, а udp позволяет посылать сообщения без установки соединения = без сервера.

Нужно только опубликовать контакт (ip, port) одного из участников и через него получить остальные. Что-то в стиле DHT. Или использовать другой месенжер (например пуши гугла, публичный сип сервер или даже смски) для обмена контактами.

Если вы новичок в сетевом программировании - то начните с месенжера с сервером. Сервер можно найти бесплатно по акции или на начальных тарифах pythonanywhere, oracle и тп. На домашнем интернете есть шанс что у вас белый адрес - можно пробросить порт.

Comment: Я встречал [статистику](https://habr.com/ru/company/odnoklassniki/blog/428217/), что у 30% народа встречается непробиваемый Symmetric NAT, что делает создание p2p-мессенджера весьма проблематичным занятием (лично я пробовал много разных p2p-мессенджеров, и ни один у меня так и не заработал нормально)

Comment: @andreymal не разу не попадал в сеть где udp продырявить не получалось. торент же качает почти везде. главное чтоб один из контактов пробился - второй сможет подключиться к нему изза симетричного ната.

у 9% остается проблема

Comment: Тем не менее в упомянутом мной посте пишут, что не удалось пробить 66%, не уверен кому верить)

Comment: в чатике на 100 человек нет морального ограничения не использовать одного из пользователей для форварда сообщений. очень интересно было бы построить mesh. поддерживать живыми 10 ребер на каждом узле и устанавливать дополнительные ребра при открытии приватов.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь использовать встроенный модуль socket.

Вот урок с использованием socket: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UohnrnZZ0w0

Вот ссылка на статью по созданию чата на Python: https://habr.com/ru/post/151623/

Answer (score 0):

В целом и общем, если нет желания арендовать сервера, то можно сделать несколько вариантов:

1. Сделать в качестве сервера свой пк
2. Сделать в качестве сервера телефон

В обоих случаях нужно открывать порты для сети и не менять её в ходе общения, что не очень удобно и не всегда возможно. Так же при таком раскладе чат будет доступен только тогда, когда телефон/пк включен и на нём запущена программа, выполняющая роль сервера.

Если нужен постоянный чат, увы, придётся арендовать `VPS`/`VDS` сервер и платить за него.

Comment: Почему бы не бесплатно заюзать большого брата? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=ru